# UICollectionviewCell Not Updating on ios 7

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

HI Am Working on `UICollectionViewCell` ,In my collectionview Total 9 cells are there  i would like Add Badge icon on CollectioviewCell at Index '1'. every time am updating Badge with int value by using buttion action. 
Problem is first time i updated badge valu by UIbutton Action , first time It works good, but second time i updated the badge shows on 8th cell , again updated badge shows on 7th cell, again updated shows on 1st position, 
[my Sample Code is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/roeuqy5avxi8d9j/collectionViewSample.zip?dl=0)

whats wrong in my code please help me..
thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show us your cell creation methods and your "badge implementation" in code ;)

Comment: @Zil Above link have total code

Comment: why did you remove `[cell.badge removeFromSuperview];`?

Comment: Woops didnt pay enough attention. Im looking right now

Comment: i just want to display on one Cell Only. at index 1

Comment: @NagRaj do you mean index `0`?

Comment: NO no mr @rebello95 index 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, i think it is reusing the cell, reset the cell every time for example replace the blow method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   cell = (HomeCollectionView *) [collectionView_ dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
   cell.CellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mahasivaratri-Lord-Shiva.jpg"];
   cell.title.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
   cell.badge.tag = indexPath.row;
   //add this 2 lines
   cell.badge.text = @""; //reset the text
   cell.badge.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width-25,5,25,25); //and also frame of badge
   //
   if (indexPath.row == 1 )
   {
          NSLog(@"unreadMessages---- Menu --- %d  and Indexpath-- %ld",UnreadMessages,(long)indexPath.row);
          NSInteger width  = [self autoBadgeSizeWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",UnreadMessages]];
          cell.badge.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-35, -10,width, 25);
          cell.badge.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",UnreadMessages];
          NSLog(@"cell frame --- %@",cell.badge);
   }
   else
   {
      //other code
   }
   return cell;
 }
```